# How to setup connection delay to Zookeeper with Curator, so it doesn't pings every second?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using Curator to connect to Zookeeper. In a situation when Zookeeper is not available I am getting constantly such events:

```
2016-09-29 12:54:22.831  INFO 43937 --- [localhost:2181)] 
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-09-29 12:54:22.832  WARN 43937 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)

2016-09-29 12:54:23.940  INFO 43937 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-09-29 12:54:23.940  WARN 43937 --- [localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn          : Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```

I can't find place where I can configure this behaviour to not happen so often. The `RetryPolicy` which is possible to set with `CuratorFramework` is not taken into consideration while trying to connect to Zookeeper for the very first time. Any advices? I would like the thread to not check the connection every second, but less often, or ideally to adapt exponential policy.

Answer (score 0):

as I understand there is no way to configure it. There is code from class ClientCnxnSocket:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        clientCnxnSocket.introduce(this,sessionId);
        clientCnxnSocket.updateNow();
        clientCnxnSocket.updateLastSendAndHeard();
        int to;
        long lastPingRwServer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int MAX_SEND_PING_INTERVAL = 10000; //10 seconds
        while (state.isAlive()) {
            try {
                if (!clientCnxnSocket.isConnected()) {
                    if(!isFirstConnect){
                        try {
       >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Thread.sleep(r.nextInt(1000));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            LOG.warn("Unexpected exception", e);
                        }
                    }
                    // don't re-establish connection if we are closing
                    if (closing || !state.isAlive()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    startConnect();
                    clientCnxnSocket.updateLastSendAndHeard();
                }
```

look at line marked with ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", I think in this place happens waiting to next try.

Comment: Yes, I was debugging that class, but actually it wasn't the path, code was executed on (the boolean flag isFirstConnect was equal `true`). The only reason it is happening every ~1 sec is native ping call made later.